# Is this an example of a Bounded Operator with NO closed range?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

My professor asked us for an example of a Bounded Operator with whose range is not closed, after some attempts I thought this, but I am not sure about it:

Consider $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and  $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the $\max$ norm, i.e  if $\mathbb{R}^n\ni x = (x_1,\dots,x_n)$ then $|| x|| = \displaystyle \max_{i=1,\dots,n}{x_i}. $ And the operator $T=\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^n$ such that, if we denote $||x||=a$ then $T:x\mapsto(a,\dots,a) \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$. This is all the non-negative multiples of the vector $(1,1,…,1)$.

Clearly $||T(x)||=||x||$, so $T$ is bounded, but I am not sure if the range is closed, for this I thought the following: We know that a set $A$ is closed iff $A^{c}$ is open. In this case $A= T(\mathbb{R}^n)$ so I can consider an element in the complement of the image of $T$, this is $y=(y_1,\dots,y_n)$ such that there are at least two $y_i$ that are different. Let's denote $b=||y||$ and consider an open ball $B(y,\epsilon)$, note that for every possible $\epsilon$ the element $T(y)$ is contained in $B(y,\epsilon)$, so there is no open ball in $A^c$ for $y$, so $A^c$ is not an open set, therefore $A$ is not a closed set.

Is this correct? I feel like I am missing something but I am not sure. If I am wrong, can you give me some other example of a bounded operator with no closed range? I saw a couple but most of the examples I found use the $L^p$ spaces that we haven't seen on class. Thanks.

Comment: Is this a linear map? You're going to have to use infinite dimensional spaces, I'm afraid. This function does have closed range, by the way. Describe the image concretely: It's all the non-negative multiples of the vector $(1,1,\dots,1)$, which is homeomorphic to the set of non-negative real numbers.

Comment: @TedShifrin I edited it with that aclaration on the image, thanks. But I don't get why you are afraid of infinite dimensional, I am only using $\mathbb{R}^n$. And jmm, now I am not sure if it is linear...

Comment: Sorry for my English. Figure out why your map isn't linear, but I'm telling you that you need infinite dimensions. Linear subspaces of finite dimension are always closed.

Comment: The term 'bounded operator' is generally used for continuous linear maps in FA. I am sure the question is about linear operators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof is faulty because $T$ is not linear ($T(-y)=T(y)$) and even so, it is not true that $T(y)$ is contained in $B(y,\epsilon)$. (Take $n=2$, $y=(1,0)$, then $T(y)=(1,1)$ is not in a small ball around $y$.) In fact, $B(y,\epsilon)\cap T(\mathbb{R}^n)=\emptyset$ for $\epsilon$ small enough.

The mapping $T : \ell^2\to\ell^2$, defined by $T (a_n) := (a_0, a_1/2, a_2/3,...)$, is linear and bounded, with $\|T\|=\pi/\sqrt6$. Its image is not closed
in $\ell^2$.

Proof: Consider $y_n:=(1, \frac{1}{2},..., \frac{1}{n}, 0, 0,...)=T(\underbrace{1,1,\ldots,1}_n,0,\ldots)\in T(\ell^2)$. It converges to the sequence $y=(1,\frac{1}{2},...)\in\ell^2$ but $y\notin T(\ell^2)$ otherwise $y=T(x)$ implies $x=(1,1,\ldots)\notin\ell^2$.

Comment: Ohh, thanks, this example I can understand, but still have a question, now I know that my proof is wrong because T is not linear, but why $B(y,\epsilon) \cap T(\mathbb{R}^n) = \varnothing$ ? In your example if I take a ball arround $y$ of radious epsilon, this contains all elements $x$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $||x||\in (1-\epsilon,1+\epsilon)$, and $||T(y)||=1$ (this is because we are not using the usual norm). Am I wrong about this?

Comment: $B(y,\epsilon)$ in the $\infty$-norm (max-norm) has the shape of a square of side $2\epsilon$. One can find such a small square around $(1,0)$ that does not touch the line $A$ (through $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$). I don't understand your second assertion. $B(y,\epsilon)$ does not contain $-y$ for example even though $\|-y\|=1$.

Comment: Ohh sorry, I was misinterpreting something, my bad. Thanks for the good examples.

Answer (score 2):

Let X be a non reflexive Banach space and $Y$ be a reflexive Banach space. Suppose that $A \colon X \to Y$ is an injective bounded linear operator. I claim that the range of $A$, denoted by $R(A)$,  can't be closed in $Y$.

Arguing by contradiction, suppose that $R(A)$ is closed and thus reflexive. Then, the operator
$  A \colon X \to R(A) $
is a continuous bijection and thus (by virtue of the Open Mapping Theorem) is an isomorphism. It's not hard to check that $X$ has to be reflexive, since it's isomorphic to a reflexive Banach space, which leads to a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Every linear subspace of a finite dimensional space is closed so there is no hope of such an example in finite dimensions. Here is a valid example: Define $Tf(x)=\int_0^{x} f(t)dt$ on $C[0,1]$. Then $\|T\|\leq 1$ but the range is not closed. The range consist precisely of continuously differentiable functions vanishing at $0$. Take any continuous function $f$ vanishing at $0$ which is not differentiable and use Weierstrass Theorem to construct a sequence polynomials in the range of $T$ converging uniformly to $f$.